# Lower Bound Absolute Value Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

**Assumptions.** Let $a_n\in \mathbf{C}$ and $b_n\in\mathbf{R}$ such that
$$
0 \ne \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n b_n \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_nb_n| < \infty.
$$
**Claim.** Let $\{c_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq \mathbf{R}$ such that $|c_n| < |b_n|$ for all $n$, then
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n c_n\right| < \left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n b_n\right|.
$$
**Ideas.** The tricky part is that the coefficients $a_n,b_n,c_n$ can change sign. If they were non-negative, it would be straightforward, but since that's not the case I do not see a clear proof.

Comment: I recommend convincing yourself that the hypothesis allow for the possibility $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n = 0$, which clearly makes the claimed inequality false.

Comment: Good catch, what if we exclude that possibility? I will edit my question, but include my comment for clarity.

Comment: @Doofenshmert Still no. We could still have a sequence of large $b_n$ that is *almost* orthogonal to the $a_n$s, but a shorter sequence $c_n$ that is roughly parallel to the $a_n$s (particularly if the $a_n$s happen to be real). Try thinking in $\Bbb{R}^2$ (i.e. take the sequences to be $0$ for $n \ge 3$) and see if you can come up with another counterexample.